# Raster Projection to UTM to Lat-Lon in R

Tags: r, raster, rgdal, proj

I am a beginner in R. I have a `rasterlayer` and I want to change its coordinate reference system (from UTM to lan-lot). I have used the following code:

```
r <-projectRaster(from = tiff,
   crs=crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
```

(Here tiff is the `rasterlayer` to be reprojected)

But  I am getting an error

> "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 439.0 Mb"

Someone, please provide a solution

Answer (score 3):

That is odd. Did you read all the values in `tiff` into memory?

The problem may go away by

- using a filename argument in projectraster. E.g. `projectRaster(tiff, filename="out.tif", crs= ...)`
- setting some rasterOptions to lower values e.g., `rasterOptions(chunksize=1e+06, maxmemory=1e+08)`

Also, it is generally *not* a good idea to use `projectRaster` with a `crs=` argument. It is better to provide a Raster* object as template to project to. In that way, you can set the extent and resolution such that the output raster will align with other raster data you are using.